# Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed [ERROR]

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I obtain this error when I do login:

```
Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.
```

The `login.php` has this code:

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    include 'config.php';
   /import sdk login.php
    require PATH.FOLDER.'facebook-php-sdk-master\\src\\Facebook\\autoload.php';

    //do login operation
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => APPID,
      'app_secret' => APPSECRET,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ['email', 'public_profile']; // Optional permissions
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(INDIRIZZORITORNO, $permissions);    
    //echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';  

    header("Location: ".$loginUrl);

    ?>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: That is only the first half of the login process. Where is your code for the second one, that exchanges the code for a token?